# Powershell code for mysql is not working

Tags: mysql, powershell

I have following code of Powershell where i am trying to sort lastest backup file of mysql database and then try to import this file 
I am using the Powershell script for this according to script till the last i get desired o/p and then i copy this o/p and execute in seprate 
cmd window it execute smooth but in power shell when i try to do the same thing it fails with following error please help me

Error message

```
  C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin\mysql.exe --user=root --password=xxx testdest < "C:\mysqltemp\testsrc_2013-12-23_10-46-AM.sql" 
cmd.exe : The system cannot find the file specified.
At C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AppData\Local\Temp\8a7b4576-97b2-42aa-a0eb-42bb934833a6.ps1:19 char:4
+ cmd <<<<  /c " "$pathtomysqldump" --user=$param1 --password=$param2 $param3 < $param5 "
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The system cann...file specified.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Script is as following

```
##Select latest file created by Export of mysql dumper
$a=(get-childitem C:\mysqltemp | sort LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object Name | select -first 1 -ExpandProperty Name)
$pathtomysqldump = "C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin\mysql.exe"
#Write-Host "Print variable A -------------"    
#$a
$a=$a.Replace(" ", "")
#Write-Host "After Triming ---------------" 
#$a
$param1="root"
$param2="xxx"
$param3="testdest"
#$param4="""'<'"""
$param5="""C:\mysqltemp\$a"""
#$p1="$param1 $param2 $param3 < $param5"
# Invoke backup Command. /c forces the system to wait to do the backup
Write-Host " "$pathtomysqldump" --user=$param1 --password=$param2 $param3 < $param5 "

cmd /c " "$pathtomysqldump" --user=$param1 --password=$param2 $param3 < $param5 "
```

Thanks and Appreciate your help and time for the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common misunderstanding involving calling command lines in the Windows operating system, particularly from PowerShell.

I highly recommend using the `Start-Process` cmdlet to launch a process instead of calling `cmd.exe`. It's much easier to mentally parse out and understand the path to the executable, and all of the command line parameters separately. The problem with your current script is that you're trying to call an executable file with the following name: `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin\mysql.exe --user=root --password=xxx testdest < "C:\mysqltemp\testsrc_2013-12-23_10-46-AM.sql"`, which has been wrapped in a call to `cmd.exe`. Obviously, that file does not exist, because you're including all of the parameters as part of the filesystem path.

There are too many layers going on here to make it simple to understand. Instead, use `Start-Process` similar to the following example:

```
# 1. Define path to mysql.exe
$MySQL = "C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin\mysql.exe"
# 2. Define some parameters
$Param1 = 'value1';
$Param2 = 'value2';
$Param3 = 'value 3 with spaces';
# 3. Build the command line arguments
# NOTE: Since the value of $Param3 has spaces in it, we must
#       surround the value with double quotes in the command line
$ArgumentList = '--user={0} --password={1} "{2}"' -f $Param1, $Param2, $Param3;
Write-Host -Object "Arguments are: $ArgumentList";

# 4. Call Start-Process
# NOTE: The -Wait parameter tells it to "wait"
#       The -NoNewWindow parameter prevents a new window from popping up
#          for the process.
Start-Process -FilePath $MySQL -ArgumentList $ArgumentList -Wait -NoNewWindow;
```

Comment: Many thanks Trevor for your swift response and i do agree with your point script is little messy i am beginner in PS forgive me i will sure implement your way to execute this script.